# Gulp SASS Sourcemap sources are incorrect

Tags: gulp, source-maps, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-autoprefixer

I am struggling to get my SASS sourcemaps to work correctly. The problem seems to be the "sources" attribute within the sourcemap and how my SASS files are nested.

I have a Gulp task that compiles SASS to CSS. Here is an example of that

```
var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: './Stylesheets/SCSS/',
        files: './Stylesheets/SCSS/**/*.scss',
        dest: './Stylesheets/CSS/'
    }
}

gulp.task('compile-sass', function (){
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.files)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            includePaths : [paths.styles.src]
        }))
        .pipe(prefix({
            browsers: ['last 2 Chrome versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../Maps/', {
            includeContent: false,
            sourceRoot: '../SCSS'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
});
```

The above works for everything else - writing maps to disk, prefixing etc. I am using latest nodejs, gulpjs and relevant npm packages.

An example of folder/asset structure from within my Stylesheets folder:

```
SCSS/print.scss  
SCSS/sectionA/style.scss  
SCSS/sectionA/partial/_partialA.scss  
SCSS/sectionA/partial/_partialB.scss  
SCSS/sectionB/... etc
```

For SASS files in the root of SCSS/ the sourcemaps work properly. Chrome will show where the source styles are.

For SASS files in a subfolder within SCSS/ the sourcemaps do not work. The problem is the "sources": attribute has the wrong file listed in it.

The print.scss map for example will correctly have `"sources":["print.scss"]`. But sectionA/style.scss map will have `"sources":["style.css"]` instead of `"sources":["partial/_partialA.scss", "partial/_partialB.scss"]` as I would expect.

I have confirmed moving /SCSS/sectionA/style.scss to /SCSS/style.scss and amending any import paths does solve the issue. But I need it to be nested, not in the root of /SCSS.

If I can provide more detail please let me know. I have tried the answer from [Path to source map is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094175/path-to-source-map-is-wrong) and it does not solve my issue. I have also tried manipulating `mapSources` with no avail.

Comment: I've seen some strange behavior reported with sourcemaps.write('../Maps/" try removing that last slash "../Maps" just to see if any difference.  Also I would do the same for paths.styles.src and paths.styles.dest.  These changes shouldn't matter but I believe I have seen some gulp fixes by removing those.

Comment: Thank you for the response Mark. I have removed the trailing slash. It did not affect my particular issue though. I have tried a non gulp solution to process the SCSS as a test [PrePos] and it handles the maps for nested partials absolutely fine. So I believe the problem lies in my Gulp task. I just can't seem to nail down where at the moment!

Comment: I have another suggestion.  Read through https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-relative-sourcemaps-source/  sometimes gulp has trouble properly setting the "sources" value.

Comment: I have just done a reduced test case. Tried to get to the basics of the problem. Created a project with a scss folder. Inside is a root.scss and a nested.scss which exists in a /nested folder. Both import their own seperate partials. After various attempts to remove any options I was passing into the various gulp modules, I can currently pin the effect on gulp-autoprefixer. If I prefix, the nested sourcemap has incorrect sources array. If I do not prefix, the nested sourcemap has correct source array. I am now trying to work out what to do about that! I may raise an issue on Github.

Comment: This is the map without prefix: {"version":3,"file":"nested.css","sources":["nested/nested.scss","nested/_sameLevel.scss"],"mappings":"ACAA,AAAA,EAAE,CAAC;EACC,UAAU,EAAE,KAAM;EAClB,UAAU,EAAE,MAAO;EACnB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAK,GACf;;AAED,AAAA,CAAC,CAAC;EACE,KAAK,EAAE,IAAK,GACf","names":[],"sourceRoot":"../../src/scss"}

Comment: This is the map with prefix: {"version":3,"sources":["nested.css"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;EACE,kBAAkB;EAClB,mBAAmB;EACnB,YAAY,EAAE;;AAEhB;EACE,YAAY,EAAE","file":"nested.css","sourceRoot":"../../src/scss"}

Comment: There is an inelegant hack here https://github.com/ByScripts/gulp-sample/blob/master/gulpfile.js that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### @ Update 2019-05-24

My answer talks about using CSSNext. [CSSNext was deprecated](https://moox.io/blog/deprecating-cssnext/). The theory in my answer is still applicable using [postcss-preset-env](https://preset-env.cssdb.org/).

### @ Update 2017-03-08

After experimenting with PostCSS, I have used CSSNext to process the CSS after SASS has converted it. CSSNext auto-prefixes and doing it this way retains the connection to the original scss files in the sourcemap.

See my [GitHub](https://github.com/freemagee/nested-sass-sourcemaps) repo for an example.

---

After following Mark's feedback and investigating the gulp-autoprefixer module I believe this [issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/55) raised on the GitHub repo for gulp-autoprefixer is related to the incorrect sourceroot problem.

Using a variation of the hack from [ByScripts](https://github.com/ByScripts/gulp-sample/blob/master/gulpfile.js) I am able to get sourcemaps with the correct sourceroot for nested scss files. The hack used in the ByScripts gulpfile inits the sourcemaps function twice. Once before prefixing, and once after.

I have created a GitHub repo to try and illustrate a reduced test case and a [workaround](https://github.com/freemagee/nested-sass-sourcemaps/blob/master/gulpfile.js). Inspecting the css produced by the workaround shows the correct relationship back to the source scss.